# Open a pop-up box, if the values are inserted in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Basically, what I'm doing is :

I have a form where user enters 'Username and Password', where the username is unique. So, if the username exists, I throw an error message. But if it doesn't exists in database I insert it. And everything works fine till here.

But now what I want to do is, when any record is inserted I show a message :

"Click here to activate your account using Email or Phone no"

And when user clicks on the Email or Phone no, I need to open a form in Pop-up window.

The main issue is to open 2 different forms, i.e. if user clicks on Email then a new form should open and if Phone no then another form should open.

Here's my sample code :

```
 <?php

    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $output = '';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        $login = 'select * from registration where username="'.trim($_POST['username']).'"';
        $data=mysqli_query($con,$login);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($login);
        if($count==0)
        {
            $insert="INSERT INTO registration (`username`,`password`) VALUES('$username','$password')";
            $data=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
            $id=mysqli_insert_id();
            if($id!='')
            {
                echo "Click here to activate your account using <a href="#">Email</a> or <a href="#">Phone no</a>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Username already registered, please choose another username.";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function openwindow (url) {
           var win = window.open(url, "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
           win.focus();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="label">Username</div>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /><br />
                <div class="label">Password</div>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
                    <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>

            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I've even applied the script, but I'm not getting how to use it basically.

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: Forms are not opening in pop-up window, on clicking the message

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
echo "Click here to activate your account using <a href="#">Email</a> or <a href="#">Phone no</a>";
```

To

```
echo "Click here to activate your account using <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"openwindow('http://abcd.com/')\">Email</a> or <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"openwindow('http://abcd.com/')\">Phone no</a>";
```